# ( ! ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in C:\wamp64\www\webapp\code.php on line 34

Tags: php, mysql

I am practicing Android Studio with MySql and i have trying a Php Script

```
   <?php
require "connect.php";
$userid = "pranav.gundra29@gmail.com";
$code=mt_rand(100000, 999999);
$mysql_qry = "select * from userinfo where userid = '$userid';";
$query = mysqli_query($conn ,$mysql_qry);

if(mysqli_num_rows($query)==1){
 $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
 $username = $row['username'];
$inserted= mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE userinfo SET password recovery='$code' WHERE userid = '$userid' ");


$to = "$userid";
$subject = "reset password link";
$header = "From: pranav@example.com". "\r\n" .
$body = "Hi $username your password reset link
To reset the password please click on the below link:
$code;

$sent=mail($to,$subject,$body,$header);

if($inserted) {

echo ' check your mail we have sent you reset link to change your password! <br>';
}


} else {
  echo ' Failed To Login ';
}


<?
```

I have used `"<?php"` at the end of file but still the same error

Please help where i am missing

Comment: `$body` variable is missing a quote..

Comment: Note the color coding above -- that should give you a hint.

Comment: Have a look at the code highlighting. It shows that there's something missing.

Comment: <? and <?php are not closing tags, they are opening tags (but only <?php should be used as <? is not guaranteed to work everywhere).

Comment: Also note that these types of errors become much easier to track down if you simply use an editor or IDE that does syntax highlighting. (Which is just about everything but notepad.)